# Best GUI Maker Software To Build Attractive GUI For Desktops OS's

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, user-interface

Kindly Tell Me What is the best software to design GUI which is the best software to design an interactive GUI as you see the Adobe GUI MS Visual Studio GUI Panda And Bitdefender GUI And All Other Interactive Softwares Out There 
I Want The Most Best GUI For My Software Software Is Desktop Based Should Work On Windows OS But OS IS Not The Major Issue But Look Should Be Attractive Moreover My Software Uses DB Access Some Code In C++ C# And Software IS Desktop Based 
I Hope You Tell the Best One With Some Book To Master That Software

In Short I Want The Best GUI Maker Software For Software Development

Comment: I bet they all did it in Assembly.

Comment: You are not looking for a software. You are either looking for a person called "UI designer" or years of learning.

Comment: [See](http://stackoverflow.com/q/88382/769220). [some](http://stackoverflow.com/q/645425/769220). [other](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5920049/769220). [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/q/460085/769220).

Comment: The Notion Of Best Is Clearly Subjective, Or There Might Not Be So Many Competing GUI Builders. You Should Try Them All Out Yourself, And Let Us Know What You Find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WPF if you're talking about .NET and use Visual Studio, Expression Blend or KaXaml to build the GUI mostly using your mouse.

You can use also Qt for C++ (or using QML in Qt) and build the GUI using QtCreator

Comment: But which one is The Best(tm)? :-) This question cannot be answered.

Comment: You have to use different instruments for different tasks (platforms etc.)